# PL SQL iterate loop through date range

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a date range, I am trying to take one date every week through a loop

```
DECLARE
  start_date DATE := TO_DATE('06.01.2021', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  end_date DATE := TO_DATE('26.05.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
  active_date DATE;
  start_number NUMBER;
  end_number NUMBER;
BEGIN
  start_number := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(start_date, 'j'));
  end_number := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(end_date, 'j'));
  active_date := start_date;
FOR cur_r IN start_number..end_number
  LOOP
   INSERT INTO test_tbl
   SELECT snap_date FROM s_act
   WHERE
    snap_date = active_date;
    active_date := TRUNC(active_date) + 7;
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
```

When I execute this script, only one date `06.01.2021`  is written to the table through all iterations.
Where am I making a mistake? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why do you do select from s_act table to insert? It seems that you need one value anyway, you could use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` syntax to avoid problems with some dates not being available in s_act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks as if everything is, actually, OK with code you wrote, because `active_date` gets its new value:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    start_date   date := to_date('06.01.2021', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  3    end_date     date := to_date('26.05.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
  4    active_date  date;
  5    start_number number;
  6    end_number   number;
  7  begin
  8    start_number := to_number(to_char(start_date, 'j'));
  9    end_number   := to_number(to_char(end_date, 'j'));
 10    active_date  := start_date;
 11
 12    for cur_r in start_number..end_number
 13    loop
 14      dbms_output.put_line('Active_date = ' || to_char(active_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
 15      /* Commented, as I don't have your tables nor data
 16         INSERT INTO test_tbl
 17           SELECT snap_date
 18           FROM s_act
 19           WHERE snap_date = active_date;
 20      */
 21      active_date := trunc(active_date) + 7;
 22    end loop;
 23    -- move COMMIT out of the loop!
 24    commit;
 25  end;
 26  /
Active_date = 06.01.2021
Active_date = 13.01.2021
Active_date = 20.01.2021
<snip>
Active_date = 06.09.2023
Active_date = 13.09.2023

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

You said

> When I execute this script, only one date `06.01.2021` is written to the table through all iterations.

This is piece of code responsible for that:

```
INSERT INTO test_tbl
  SELECT snap_date 
  FROM s_act
  WHERE snap_date = active_date;
```

I interpret it as:

- `s_act` table contains rows **only** with `snap_date` equal to `06.01.2021`, or
- if it contains rows with other dates, maybe they contain a *time component* (hours, minutes, seconds) and `where` condition prevents them to be inserted. If that's so, try with

  ```
  where trunc(snap_date) = active_date
  ```

  and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need PL/SQL for this and can just use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_tbl
WITH date_range ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-06', DATE '2021-05-26' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_date + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         end_date
  FROM   date_range
  WHERE  start_date + INTERVAL '7' DAY <= end_date
)
SELECT snap_date
FROM   s_act s
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   date_range r
         WHERE  r.start_date = s.snap_date
       );
```

or a hierarchical query:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_tbl
SELECT snap_date
FROM   s_act s
WHERE  EXISTS(
         WITH date_range ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
           SELECT DATE '2021-01-06', DATE '2021-05-26' FROM DUAL
         )
         SELECT 1
         FROM   date_range r
         WHERE  r.start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '7' DAY = s.snap_date
         CONNECT BY r.start_date + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '7' DAY <= r.end_date
       );
```

---

If you really want to use PL/SQL then you can make it much simpler and iterate by weeks rather than days (however, this will be much less efficient as you will have one `INSERT` per week and the associated context switch from PL/SQL to SQL compared to the SQL solution which is only a single `INSERT` for the entire operation and no context switches):

```sql
DECLARE
  start_date  DATE := DATE '2021-01-06';
  end_date    DATE := DATE '2021-05-26';
  active_date DATE := start_date;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN active_date > end_date;

    INSERT INTO test_tbl
    SELECT snap_date FROM s_act
    WHERE  snap_date = active_date;

    active_date := active_date + INTERVAL '7' DAY;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=697f8eca92d407280a5a01b386ae841b)*

Comment: In this loop, in addition to the date, I will need to collect other data from other tables. What I wrote earlier is some kind of baseline to make sure that the loop is working correctly

Comment: @Sam324 Updated with a PL/SQL loop.